# TableAdapter with multiple "LIKE" constraints

Tags: vb.net

I'm using an Access database in my VB program and sorting it if a field has a value.

How would I add multiple conditions? Like if two values exist then show the results.

This is what I have now:

```
FROM    Orders
WHERE    ([Level] LIKE 'DD')
```

How would I add `([NAME] Like 'Smith')` to the constraints as well?

Comment: chain them together using AND or OR as appropriate. Just like any SQL WHERE condition. BTW using LIKE without a wildcard at the start or end as per your example doesn't make much sense, you might as well just use = and save processing time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could even be more specific with your conditions and even combine a couple of them:

```
''' I added wildcards for the example
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE ([Level] LIKE '%DD%' AND ([NAME] LIKE '%Smith%' OR [NAME] LIKE '%Wilson%')) " & _
"OR ([Level] LIKE '%BB%' AND ([NAME] LIKE '%Sandy%' OR [NAME] LIKE '%Willy%'))
```

This Query would return results where [Level] contains DD and [NAME] contains either Smith or Wilson.  It will also return results where [Level] contains BB and [NAME] contains either Sandy or Willy.  The Possibilities are endless depending on your conditions.

Just FYI.  "John" and "john" are different.  Incorporate something like this into your query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE LCASE(field1) = LCASE(input)
```

[MS Access: LCase Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/lcase.php)

It will make your search more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to append the conditions with `AND`:

```
FROM Orders WHERE ( [Level] LIKE 'DD' ) AND ( [NAME] Like 'Smith' )
```

Comment: It's SQL not vb.net